# Which CS-23 airplane has the lowest takeoff speed?

Tags: aircraft-performance, takeoff, cs-23

Among the currently certified [CS-23 airplanes](https://www.easa.europa.eu/system/files/dfu/agency-measures-docs-certification-specifications-CS-23-CS-23-Amdt-3.pdf) (or "Part 23" in FAA-land or your personal region equivalent), which has the lowest rotation speed ($V_r$)?